# Pandas cannot call function on a datetimeindex

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to call a `dayofweek()` on my datetimeindex in a dataframe. Here is my code:

```
v = [
[
    1582041084.72,
    "1989121.03"
],
[
    1582041684.72,
    "1989121.03"
]


df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(v, columns=['time', 'points'])
df = df.astype({'points': 'float'})
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], unit='s')
df = df.set_index('time')
filtered = df.between_time('10:00', '14:30')

print(filtered.index.dayofweek())
```

This returns an error saying `'Int64Index' object is not callable`.

Here's the output of `df.index`:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2020-02-19 10:01:24.720000029',
               '2020-02-19 10:11:24.720000029'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='time', freq=None)
```

Comment: Problem is in sample data is filtered empty dataframe, check `print (filtered)`

Comment: Its not empty...

Comment: it is on the example

Comment: I got `print(df.index) 
DatetimeIndex(['2020-02-18 15:51:24.720000029', '2020-02-18 16:01:24.720000029'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='time', freq=None)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dayofweek` doesn't need `()`.
Simply do:

```
print(df.index.dayofweek)
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that [`dayofweek`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.dayofweek.html) is a *property* and not a method.

That means you should use it without the parens:

```
print(filtered.index.dayofweek)
```

You can see that that's what the error message is telling you, `'Int64Index' object` being the result of the property and it's complaining that you're trying to "call" it as a function, but it `is not callable`.